# Show all ports as opened

Tags: linux, ubuntu, port

Would I be able to set all portstates to OPEN for scanners like nmap?
Some attackers may scan my host and see all ports opened from 1 to 65535, but that no ports have actual services behind them running ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have something listening on all of them.. but this really doesn't provide additional security; the `-A` option of nmap will pretty quickly filter the real ones from the fakes.